# Wrapping boost::function with a C++/CLI class event

Tags: events, boost, c++-cli

I'm trying to figure out how to wrap a boost::function member (used as an event callback) of an unmanaged class with a C++/CLI class event.  I do not have control over the unmanaged class.  All I can do is figure out how to write the C++/CLI class properly.

Here's the example unmanaged class:

```
class X
{
public:
    boost::function<void (double)> XChanged;;

    void Set(double x)
    {
        XChanged(x)
    }
};
```

I've tried many things, but I keep running into problems.  I'm sure it's easier than it appears to be.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

CLI probably won't let you declare a boost::function as a static member.  Make it a pointer:

`boost::function<void(double> *XChanged;`

Then allocate/deallocate in the constructor and finalizer and call it with (*XChanged)(arg);